# How to create parameters with arrays?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set a parameter as an array, but I get "unexpected token..." at {name[2]}.

```
// javascript


const name = ['Jin', 'Kazuya', 'Heiachi']
function Intro(name, profession, city) {
    document.write("My name is " + name + ", I'm a" + profession + " from" + city);
}

Intro({name[2]}, ' salesman', ' Chicago');
```

Comment: Remove the curly brackets `Intro(name[2], ' salesman', ' Chicago');`

Comment: why are you wrapping it in curly braces?

Comment: use this.Intro(name[2], ' salesman', ' Chicago');

Answer (score -1):

```
const name = ['Jin', 'Kazuya', 'Heiachi']
function Intro(name, profession, city) {
    document.write("My name is " + name + ", I'm a" + profession + " from" + city);
}

Intro(name[2], ' salesman', ' Chicago');
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the input, but I see now that 'name' has already been declared as a parameter. But still struggling to make parameter = const name = [array]

Comment: what do you try to do?